# How To use security enforcement with dynamic database.query in apex?

Tags: community, dynamic-soql, dynamic-apex

```
String objkey='Opportunity';
string recordID = '0061k000007Pyuf';
string soqlQueryCurrent='Id, Name, currency_Culture__c';
string queryStr ='SELECT '+soqlQueryCurrent+' FROM '+objkey+ ' WHERE id=:recordID' ; 
sObject sObjRecords = Database.query(string.escapeSingleQuotes(queryStr));
system.debug('sObjRecords: '+sObjRecords);
```

How To use security enforcement with dynamic database.query  in this sample code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **WITH_SECURITY** keyword in your dynamic SOQL to enforce Field level security!

If you want record level security then make sure you use these queries in class that has `with sharing` keyword.

```
string queryStr ='SELECT '+soqlQueryCurrent+' FROM '+objkey+ ' WHERE id=:recordID' ;
queryStr += ' WITH_SECURITY'
sObject sObjRecords = 
Database.query(string.escapeSingleQuotes(queryStr));
system.debug('sObjRecords: '+sObjRecords);
```

Add the above before you do database.query to your query string.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried "WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED" ?

Example:

```
Id recordId = '0035f000003HS1sAAG';
String q = 'SELECT ID from Contact WHERE id = :recordId WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED LIMIT 1';
System.debug(Database.query(String.escapeSingleQuotes(q)));
```

in your case:

```
string queryStr ='SELECT '+soqlQueryCurrent+' FROM '+objkey+ ' WHERE id=:recordID WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED' ;
sObject sObjRecords = 
Database.query(string.escapeSingleQuotes(queryStr));
system.debug('sObjRecords: '+sObjRecords);
```

Another option is to use "Security.stripInaccessible"

For example:

```
String objkey='Opportunity';
string recordID = '0061k000007Pyuf';
string soqlQueryCurrent='Id, Name, currency_Culture__c';
string queryStr ='SELECT '+soqlQueryCurrent+' FROM '+objkey+ ' WHERE id=:recordID' ; 
SObjectAccessDecision securityDecision = Security.stripInaccessible(AccessType.READABLE, Database.query(String.escapeSingleQuotes(queryStr)));
System.debug('sObjRecords: ' + securityDecision.getRecords());
```

It will return the fields and values, visible to a user (READABLE)

Possible checks are
CREATABLE,
READABLE,
UPDATABLE,
UPSERTABLE

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). When you copied/pasted @MohithShrivastava 's answer, you failed to change his WITH_SECURITY to your WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED.

Comment: Thanks, I've removed extra "WITH_SECURITY".